# How to handle this json with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

Alright so I'm kind of hung up on how I should go about this when it comes to using Room. I'm still relatively newb when it comes to sql and subsequently Room.
I have multiple different responses that I am going to have to deal with but I'm not sure how I would store and reference them. Examples of responses are as follow:

```
[
  {
    "watchers": 21,
    "movie": {
      "title": "TRON: Legacy",
      "year": 2010,
      "ids": {
        "trakt": 1,
        "slug": "tron-legacy-2010",
        "imdb": "tt1104001",
        "tmdb": 20526
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "watchers": 17,
    "movie": {
      "title": "The Dark Knight",
      "year": 2008,
      "ids": {
        "trakt": 4,
        "slug": "the-dark-knight-2008",
        "imdb": "tt0468569",
        "tmdb": 155
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And

```
[
  {
    "collected_at": "2014-09-01T09:10:11.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-09-01T09:10:11.000Z",
    "movie": {
      "title": "TRON: Legacy",
      "year": 2010,
      "ids": {
        "trakt": 1,
        "slug": "tron-legacy-2010",
        "imdb": "tt1104001",
        "tmdb": 20526
      }
    },
    "metadata": {
      "media_type": "bluray",
      "resolution": "hd_1080p",
      "hdr": "dolby_vision",
      "audio": "dts",
      "audio_channels": "6.1",
      "3d": false
    }
  },
  {
    "collected_at": "2014-09-01T09:10:11.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-09-01T09:10:11.000Z",
    "movie": {
      "title": "The Dark Knight",
      "year": 2008,
      "ids": {
        "trakt": 6,
        "slug": "the-dark-knight-2008",
        "imdb": "tt0468569",
        "tmdb": 155
      }
    },
    "metadata": {
      "media_type": "bluray",
      "resolution": "hd_1080p",
      "hdr": "dolby_vision",
      "audio": "dts",
      "audio_channels": "6.1",
      "3d": false
    }
  }
]
```

These are just 2 examples of the responses I have to handle. Here is the "Movie" data class and it's parent "Trending"

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Movie(
    @Json(name = "ids")
    val ids: Ids?,
    @Json(name = "ratings")
    val ratings: Ratings?,
    @Json(name = "stats")
    val stats: Stats?,
    @Json(name = "summary")
    val summary: Summary?,
    @Json(name = "title")
    val title: String?,
    @Json(name = "year")
    val year: Int?
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Trending(
        @Json(name = "movie")
        val movie: Movie?,
        @Json(name = "show")
        val show: Show?,
        @Json(name = "watchers")
        val watchers: Int?
    )
```

My understanding is that the Trending data class would have a One-to-Many relationship with the Movies, depending on what's in the list. I guess my question is instead of using the MoshiConverterFactory to do all the parsing, I think I am going to have to manually handle the response.

Comment: you can use volley to parse json request https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#kotlin

Comment: It's not the parsing that I am having trouble with. How will I store these objects in Room and reference them relative to one another. Movie can be referenced by multiple data classes, not just the Trending class